# After adding the SessionState tag in web.config file, URL gets changed.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application.

I have added the below code in web.config to handle session.

```
 <system.web>
       <sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="true"   timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
```

after adding this code , when I run the application  , I get the following url in browser.

```
http://localhost:65344/(S(egpaesodxcoii0dxtczyi10c))/Login/LoginUser
```

I am confused about (S(egpaesodxcoii0dxtczyi10c)) this part.

if I remove this SessionState tag

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="true"   timeout="30" />
```

from web config then it start appearing normal like below

```
http://localhost:65344/Login/LoginUser
```

whats the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue.

When you use Cookieless sessionstates, the user's sessionId is embedded in the url. If you do not want this embedded you should consider setting Cookieless to false.

I recommend you have a read of this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) it should outline the differences between the two.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that session state can store the unique ID that associates the client with a server session: by storing an HTTP cookie on the client or by encoding the session ID in the URL. Storing the session ID in the cookie is more secure but requires the client browser to support cookies.

For applications that allow clients that do not support cookies, such as a variety of mobile devices, the session ID may be stored in the URL. The URL option has several drawbacks. It requires that the links on the site be relative and that the page be redirected at the beginning of the session with new query-string values, and it exposes the session ID right in the query string, where it can be picked up for use in a security attack.
You are encouraged to use the cookieless mode only if you need to support clients that lack cookie support.

So setting : cookieLess to False will work for you

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="false"   timeout="30" />
</system.web>
```